# JavaScript validation function on Firefox

Tags: javascript, ajax, firefox, dom-events

I have the following code which works perfect in IE for a textarea element.

```
<textarea name="mem_message" cols="25" rows="5"
  onkeypress="return taLimit(this)" 
  onkeyup="return taCount(this,'myCounter')">
    <? echo $_SESSION['mem_message']; ?>
</textarea>
```

It calls a validation function:

```
<script language="Javascript"><!--Counter for Message Box -->

maxL=100;
var bName = navigator.appName;
function taLimit(taObj) {
    if (taObj.value.length==maxL) return false;
    return true;
}

function taCount(taObj,Cnt) { 
    objCnt=createObject(Cnt);
    objVal=taObj.value;
    if (objVal.length>maxL) objVal=objVal.substring(0,maxL);
    if (objCnt) {
        if(bName == "Netscape"){    
            objCnt.textContent=maxL-objVal.length;}
        else{objCnt.innerText=maxL-objVal.length;}
    }
    return true;
}
function createObject(objId) {
    if (document.getElementById) return document.getElementById(objId);
    else if (document.layers) return eval("document." + objId);
    else if (document.all) return eval("document.all." + objId);
    else return eval("document." + objId);
}
</script>
```

All the above works on IE only. On Firefox it won't even focus on the box.

Comment: as a side note: calling the last function "createObject" is a bit misleading since you aren't creating anything but rather "get"ting it.

Comment: Don't know what you mean by "won't focus on the box", you're not calling focus() anywhere as far as I can tell.  You mean if you click in it?  Tab to it?

Comment: Works for me... suspect the error is somewhere else

Comment: Won't allow to place cursor inside textarea element or edit it's contents. Only works in IE

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Few pointers:

- Don't use language="javascript", it's deprecated.
- Don't use `eval` for property access, it's slow and unnecessary.
- Don't sniff for "Netscape", instead check property/method existence/compliance (innerText/textContent)
- Don't name a method for receiving an element as "createObject", it's misleading.
- Don't perform undeclared assignment (`maxL = 100`), it's error prone.
- Don't capitalize variable names that are not constructors (or namespaces), for convention.
- Try not to declare functions in global scope, to avoid name conflicts.

Comment: All good points, and nearly any of which might account for things not quite working.

Comment: Actually "T.J. Crowder" the problem was solved by implementing "Kangax" first pointer and simply changing the script option to be type="text/javascript". Working properly. If your not helping, please don't trash contributors, learn instead. Thanks "Kangar" !

Answer (score 1):

Here's a better script to count characters in a textarea: http://sliceofcake.wordpress.com/2007/08/16/count-characters-in-a-textarea/

Hope it's what you're looking for!

Comment: Thanks Emil, no need now. It was a faulty SCRIPT tag attribute.

Answer (score 0):

The attributes for event handlers are meant to be in all lower case; have you tried onkeyup rather than onKeyUp, etc.?

Comment: Someone seems to have edited the question to make the attributes all lower case now.

Comment: These attributes will not be parsed differently by the browser. These are HTML tags, and are not case sensitive. onKeyPress and onKeyUp are html attributes not javascript.

Comment: It depends what `DOCTYPE` you're using. You're quite correct about the HTML doctypes, though.

Answer (score 0):

Please read Unobtrusive JavaScript here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript before doing any development in JavaScript.

You will thank me many times over later!